# pyautogui.click hangs/stops Programm

Tags: pyautogui

When I call the pyautogui.click function the click gets executed, but then the programm stops. When i press ctrl+c the programm runs again.

I simplefied my problem

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(956, 222)
print("Hello")
```

You would expect that it clicks and prints but it clicks, waits until i press ctrl+c and than prints.

It used to work.

I already tried other versions of pyautogui, every time the same.
I now also tried it with win32api and it works one time, after that same problem as pyautogui.

btw my first post, sry if syntax highlighting is wrong

Comment: Did you find any solution? i'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. When using the .click or the .press function with pyautogui it will click, but then hang on that line.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling with no luck. I also had pynput installed at the same time, when trying pynput again it was also plagued with the same bug with it hanging up on the click or press for the mouse.

I solved it by uninstalling pynput, pyautogui, and removing it's modules from the folder. Restarted my computer and installed pynput.
Works with no problem now. Uninstalled pynput and installed pyautogui and now it works too.
Not sure if they constrained one another or the computer just needed a restart.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of the details of why it's caused but it happens because of the print statement. The 2 ways I know how to fix this:

1. Remove the print statement
2. OR have your mouse outside of the terminal when the program starts

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue with `pyautogui`, `pynput` and `win32api`, not sure why.

I worked out a hack for your case by putting `pyautogui.click` into a separate process:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time
import pyautogui


def click_process(x, y):
    pyautogui.click(x, y)


def click(x, y):
    clicking = multiprocessing.Process(target=click_process, args=(x, y))
    clicking.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    clicking.terminate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    click(956, 222)
    print('Hello')
```

Unfortunately, now I'm facing another issue - the process does not get terminated. The program makes a click and prints `Hello` like intended, but it does not quit. Also if you print active children with `multiprocessing.active_children()` after trying to terminate you'll still see a hanging child process. I tried using kill() instead of terminate() and tried killing it by pid with os and psutil - still hanging.